# word substitution with incremented number 

Tags: sed, substitution

I have a large text file where the word DATA appears more than 10000 times. I would like to know how can a make a conditional substitution, so the first time it appears in the document it is changed to NO1 and the second time to NO2 and so on, using bash. I was thinking about some complicated script using bash but there must be an easier way, I guess.

Comment: Does the word *DATA* ever occur more than once on the same line?

Comment: With that many occurrences of the string to substitute, you don't want to do this using the shell, but rather some utility. I took the liberty to remove the bash tag and rephrase the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/DATA/ "NO" . ++$n /ge' file_in > file_out
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '{
     for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
          if ($i == "DATA") printf("%s%s", "NO"++n, OFS); 
           else  printf("%s%s", $i, OFS)      
          if (i==NF) printf "\n"
     }      
  }' file > outFile
```

OR as glenn jackman rightly points out, this can be boiled down to

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="DATA") $i = "NO" ++n} {print}' file > outFile
```

I leave my original version in place to show an alternate (but overwrought) approach ;-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: save printing until after examining the words: `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="DATA") $i = "NO" ++n} {print}'`